# Can't get ref of underlying button?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Using react-bootstrap: I'd like to get the DOM node of the actual button (why? because I'm using clipboardJS which requires a DOM node event handler), but this ref doesn't work:

```
<Button ref="myButton">Click me!</Button>
```

The ref returned there is to the Button component, not the actual button node. Of course I could do:

```
const buttonNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.myButton)
```

But findDOMNode is going away and I'd really like to avoid that hack if possible. It would seem like react-bootstrap could use a Component-level prop to help in these situations:

```
<Button innerRef="myButton">Click Me!</Button> {/* wishful thinking... */}
```

What am I misunderstanding? Much thanks for any help.

Comment: What React version?

Comment: What is the error exactly ? where you are calling `this.refs.myButton` ? More code is needed

Comment: Andrew: react 15.4.2

Comment: Abdennour: in my case, the code which references the ref is: this.clipboard = new Clipboard(this.refs.button); (see clipboardJS) - but that doesn't really matter. This is a more general question about react-bootstrap since it's components "wrap" interior native nodes, I'm not seeing how to pass the ref to the native node inside the react-bootstrap component. So I suspect my Clipboard case is just one of many possible problem cases... thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I want the `HTMLButtonElement` but `ref={(button) => ...}` gives me the `react-bootstrap.Button`.

Comment: no solution yet, but I've not revisited this since my original posting. Sorry.